# Flip card animation

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a card game made with Xamarin forms, and I currently have three separate view with the same card.

What I want to do is to show the first card

[selection card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhGCy.png)

When you click on Truth (Verdad), the selection card will flip and show this

[truth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mo8kp.png)

If you click dare, it will flip and show this

[Dare](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxwNV.png)

I tried to create a custod render, but xamarin dosent want to build my resorce.designer.cs, with has all he animations

[files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO4Il.png)

Comment: "xamarin dosent want to build my resorce.designer.cs" - is there an error when you build?  What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the issue might be happening because the following reasons:

- Files in your Resource/anim might have the wrong build action the correct one is AndroidResource,
- If that does not fix the issue just delete the resource.designer.cs file, it's an autogenerated file and once you delete the bin and obj and rebuild the project it will be autogenerated.

Good luck, let me know in case if you have queries.

Comment: do you happen to know how to flip it and show in the same screen